# Getting error running SSIS package on non-SSIS Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm working in SSDT 2012.  I've created a DTSX package that I have deployed to a SQL Server that does not have SSIS installed.  My undertstanding is that this should work.

However I keep getting the following error: 
***To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Services or Higher.***

I'm not really sure what's going on here.  Does anyone have any insight for this.  I've asked our DBA to install SSIS on the machine but I'm only guessing.  This may not work and I would like to get ahead of this if I can.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: As referenced on your question on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53333/running-ssis-on-sql-server-without-ssis-installed), you must have have the [SSIS component installed](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the package to execute on the server, you do need to have SQL Server Integration Services engine installed on the server.

Comment: Installed SSIS on server and it worked like a charm.  Seems that non-SSIS specific functions work without the install, but SSIS-specific ones require it.  Thanks again for the quick and excellent help.