# Does SSIS Components have to be installed on all involved hosts?

Tags: mysql, ssis, ssis-2012

**TLDR;** I am attempting to connect to a host and hitting "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Services or higher". **Does SSIS need to be installed on all Hosts for my package to succeed?** Secondary question: If so, why would a manual execution from my dev machine work while the deployed/dtexec versions fail?

Apologies if this is a basic question (I am still steeping myself in all things SSIS and trying to learn as quickly as possible). Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

I have a package that runs fine on my development machine (via Visual Studio). However, when I deploy the package out I encounter errors when attempting to connect to a MySQL database on a secondary host machine on the network. Taking a step back, I decided to attempt a manual execution via DTEXEC on my dev machine to attempt troubleshooting...

When executing this package through DTEXEC however, I encounter an error stating:

```
"To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Services or higher"
```

Looking at the log, it looks like the package is able to connect to Host 1 successfully and do some data manipulation (one of the 3 hosts; I know Host 1 and Host 3 have SSIS installed). However, when it attempts connection to Host 2, it fails with the aforementioned error. For the longest time, I thought this was due to the MySQL database I am trying to connect to (using .net Provider\MySQL Data Provider) but given the error above, it is possibly pointing to something else...

After doing a bit of searching I have located the following articles which may be related:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/error-to-run-a-ssis-package-outside-of-sql-server-data-tools-you-must-install

[Getting error running SSIS package on non-SSIS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989099/getting-error-running-ssis-package-on-non-ssis-server)

I know SSIS isn't installed on Host 2. The package is being executed from Host 1 and this host does have SQL Server and SSIS installed. Host 3 additionally has SQL Server and SSIS installed and I am able to successfully operate/connect on this host as well. The only host presenting a problem is Host 2 which does not have SQL Server nor SSIS installed.

Do all hosts have to have SSIS installed for connections to be made? Additionally, if SSIS does need to installed on Host 2, why would my dev machine succeed while the dtexec/deployed versions fail?

Again, thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: What type of data manipulation your package is doing on Hosts? Is it data extract from DB, or something else?

Comment: On Host 2, it is purely data extraction. No data manipulation (edit/insert) is done. Just connect, extract some data, and disconnect.

Comment: could you be more specific - what do you mean by "connect" and "extract". How do you do this - connect to DBMS, or to a file share, how do you extract data. Is host 2 a DB server and you extract data with OLE DB, it will be fine without SSIS binaries; in that case problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is "Yes", and that fact is the answer to your secondary question.

In short, SSIS packages are **NOT** self-contained executable files.   They are more like .ini files that the SSIS Service reads, interprets, and executes.  If the SSIS Service is not running on a host computer, then that computer cannot do anything with an SSIS package (the .dtsx file).

Your dev machine succeeds because it has Visual Studio, or BIDS, which is a developer's version of the SSIS Service engine.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is extremely helpful! As I understand it then, I will need to install the SSIS Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services) on each host I am connecting out to so that, when an attempted connection is performed, the SSIS Service on that host machine will take the correct action to complete the package. I am working with various SYSAdmin and just want to make sure I convey the need appropriately. Thanks again for you assistance! It is very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the word "host" correctly.   A "host" is a computer that hosts an application, such as SSIS.   If SSIS is just grabbing data from a database on another computer, that computer is a "data source", not a "host", and it doesn't need to have the SSIS Service installed.

Comment: Apologies on butchering the nomenclature; thank you for your assistance! You have been extremely helpful!